# calculate csjs id of a name picker control

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a name picker with ID namePickerVisitors. How can I access it's ID via CSJS?

I tried

```
x$("#{id:namePickerVisitors}").hide();
```

but in the DOM I notice is has no generated ID. It just has become an anchor link with ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try wrapping it in a div with and id and then hide that?

Comment: that is what I am doing now :-)